# Why does `g_array_append_val` segfault when the element size is bigger than the actual value size?

Tags: c, memory, glib

My program segfaulted in a code that looks like the following:

```
user_t user;
users = g_array_sized_new(FALSE, TRUE, sizeof(*user), nb_results);
g_array_append_val(users, user);
```

At line 3, instead of adding user by value I add it by pointer. This will segfault sometime. The correct does initialize the `GArray` to host pointers:

```
users = g_array_sized_new(FALSE, TRUE, sizeof(user_t *), nb_results);
g_array_append_val(users, user);
```

I don't understand why the first version of this code does segfault since `sizeof(*user)` is bigger than `sizeof(user_t *)`.

Comment: Even if the array is large enough to store your items, glib must know the exact size in order to perform pointer arithmetic , i.e: `*(obj->elem + obj->size * position) = x`

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity's sake, lets say that `sizeof *user` is six bytes, and a pointer is four bytes. That means an array of two users have 12 bytes, enough space for three pointers. ***But*** when you get an element from that array it will get a six-byte element, which will contain one and a half pointer.

When you try to store this value into a pointer, you will get half of the first pointer and half of the other pointer. That will not be valid and when you dereference it you will get *undefined behavior*.